# PHP date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface

Tags: php, date, datetime, date-format

I want to convert the string to date time, but it's not working

```
<?php  
$date = date_create_from_format('d_m_Y_H_i_s', '29_11_2016_5_0_15');
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
```

return

```
Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, boolean given ...
```

what is the solution ??

Comment: 29_11_2016_05_00_15

Comment: `date_create_from_format` returns `false`, that's the problem. If you aren't using the 24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros, use `G` instead of `H`. For the minute, you _must_ add the leading zeros, you can add it yourself.

Comment: @Qirel date format ( day_month_year_hour_minute_second)

Comment: @Federkun, i got the same error

Answer (score 0):

[`date_create_from_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) returns false when it fails, or a new DateTime instance when it succeeds.

Yours is failing because minutes are two-digits, not single-digits. Using `29_11_2016_5_0_15` as a timestring would yield the following error

> A two digit minute could not be found

So simply, you'll need to use `29_11_2016_5_00_15` as the timestring instead, like this

```
// Try to create the datetime instance
if ($date = date_create_from_format('d_m_Y_H_i_s', '29_11_2016_5_00_15')) {
    echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
} else {
    // It failed! Errors found, let's figure out what!
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r(date_get_last_errors());
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

The output from the above snippet would be `2016-11-29`, live demo: https://3v4l.org/6om9g

Using [`date_get_last_errors()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.getlasterrors.php) you'll be able to get the errors given in your DateTime instance.

Answer (score 0):

You must use [minutes](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) with two chars, in your code is just one where shoud with leading 0.

so just pad it with leading 0.

```
<?php
$string = '29_11_2016_5_0_15';
$array = explode('_', $string);
$array[4] = str_pad($array[4], 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
$string = implode('_', $array);
$date = date_create_from_format('d_m_Y_H_i_s', $string);
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I format date:
echo date("d/m/Y  H:i:s a", strtotime($row['timestamp']));
```